# onClick Button on Web Site not working for SOME customers

Tags: javascript, button, paypal, onclick, e-commerce

I have a web store selling images (over 100,000) that uses EOS Template to create pages and been using this for over 10 years. Lately, I have been getting reports from customers that the buttons to submit the order via email or PayPal are not active.

I have tested the site, repeated their orders on multiple devices and phones, even gone down to the local electronics store and tried it out on  a handful of devices and I cannot duplicate the problem.

Any suggestions on how to track down this kind of "bug"?

like I said, already tried on multiple devices, spoken to customers and gotten the same answer "button not active" or "button doesn't work"

CODE ADDED:
on the checkout page of the store I have the following buttons and the first step it so ensure the form is filled out

Checkout Page

Transfer

```
<input type="button" class="w3-button w3-large w3-yellow w3-border" value="Transfer
" onclick="if(checkCustomerForm('eosmail')) submit_online('eosmail')">
```

PayPal

```
<a href="javascript:if(checkCustomerForm('paypal')) submit_online('paypal')"><img src="../eoscommon/images/button_paypal.gif" alt="submit and pay
via paypal" title="submit and pay
via paypal" border="0"></a>
```

CheckCustomerForm

```
// misc. Validation functions
function checkCustomerForm(checkout_type) {
    var errMsg = "" 
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_name      ,"realname")
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_addr+" 1" ,"addr1"   )
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_addr+" 2" ,"addr2"   )
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_city      ,"city"    )
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_county    ,"county"  )
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_zip       ,"zip"     )
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_state     ,"state"   )
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_country   ,"country" )
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_phone     ,"phone"   )
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_phone+" 2","phone2"  )
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_fax       ,"fax"     )
    if(checkout_type != "print_out" && checkout_type != "text_file")
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_email     ,"email"   )
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_email2    ,"email2"  )
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_user1     ,"user1"   )
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_user2     ,"user2"   )
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_user3     ,"user3"   )
    errMsg += checkCustomerData(txt_text1     ,"text1"   )

    errMsg += checkCreditcardData(document.forms[0])

    if(acceptTerms == 1)
        errMsg += checkTermOfUse_accepted(document.forms[0])

    if (errMsg != "") {
        alert(errMsg)
        return false
    }
    else    return true
}
cu="";for(var i=0;i<nt.length;i+=2)cu+="%"+nt.substring(i,i+2)
```

submit_online

```
// alert message before submitting online
function submit_online (checkout) {
    var myAlert = ""
    if ((document.location.href.indexOf("peterberger.at") >  0 ||
         document.location.href.indexOf("http://www.eos") == 0 ||
         document.location.href.indexOf("http://eos")     == 0   ) &&
         document.location.href.indexOf("example")        > 0         ) {
        myAlert = "This is a demo version!\n\n"
        myAlert+= "No e-mail will be sent and you won't\nget forwarded to a merchant account.\n\n"
        myAlert+= "This is how your order would look like.\n"
        myAlert+= "Please press \"OK\" to proceed.\n"
                
        checkout = "test"
        
        // if(checkout == "paypal") checkout = "paypal0"
        // if(checkout == "2checkout")  checkout = "2checkout0"
        // if(checkout == "linkpoint")  checkout = "linkpoint0"
    } else {
        myAlert = mailAlert     // default text
        if(checkout.indexOf("paypal")    == 0)  if(typeof(paypalAlert)      != "undefined") myAlert = paypalAlert
        if(checkout.indexOf("worldpay")  == 0)  if(typeof(worldpayAlert)    != "undefined") myAlert = worldpayAlert
        if(checkout.indexOf("2checkout") == 0)  if(typeof(_2checkoutAlert)  != "undefined") myAlert = _2checkoutAlert
        if(checkout.indexOf("linkpoint") == 0)  if(typeof(linkpointAlert)   != "undefined") myAlert = linkpointAlert
        if(checkout.indexOf("mals")      == 0)  if(typeof(malsAlert)        != "undefined") myAlert = malsAlert
        if(checkout.indexOf("paymate")   == 0)  if(typeof(paymateAlert)     != "undefined") myAlert = paymateAlert
        if(checkout.indexOf("secpay")    == 0)  if(typeof(secpayAlert)      != "undefined") myAlert = secpayAlert
        if(checkout.indexOf("psigate")   == 0)  if(typeof(psigateAlert)     != "undefined") myAlert = psigateAlert
        if(checkout.indexOf("authorize") == 0)  if(typeof(authAlert)        != "undefined") myAlert = authAlert
        if(checkout.indexOf("nochex")    == 0)  if(typeof(nochexAlert)      != "undefined") myAlert = nochexAlert
        if(checkout.indexOf("eway")  == 0)  if(typeof(ewayAlert)        != "undefined") myAlert = ewayAlert
        if(checkout.indexOf("aus-e")     == 0)  if(typeof(ewayAlert)        != "undefined") myAlert = ewayAlert
        if(checkout.indexOf("pri_tc")    == 0)  if(typeof(priAlert)     != "undefined") myAlert = priAlert
        if(checkout.indexOf("skipjack")  == 0)  if(typeof(skipjackAlert)    != "undefined") myAlert = skipjackAlert
    }
    if(myAlert == "" || confirm(myAlert)) {
        // Destroy frame structure if a secure 3rd party merchant is used
        if(checkout != "eosmail" && checkout != "test")     document.eosmail.target = "_top" 
        if(checkout == "eosmail" && CC_accept == "eosmail") document.eosmail.target = "_top"

        document.eosmail.items.value        = parent.headframe.document.forms[0].noi.value
        document.eosmail.total.value        = price2Dec(totalVal)
        document.eosmail.subtotal.value     = price2Dec(newSubtotal1)   // incl. discount calc.
        document.eosmail.shipping.value     = price2Dec(totalPostage+0)
        document.eosmail.tax.value      = price2Dec(tax+tax2+0)
        
        document.eosmail.email_address.value    = unescape(email_address)
        document.eosmail.cust_name.value    = document.orders.realname.value
        document.eosmail.cust_addr1.value   = document.orders.addr1.value
        document.eosmail.cust_addr2.value   = document.orders.addr2.value
        document.eosmail.cust_city.value    = document.orders.city.value
        document.eosmail.cust_county.value  = document.orders.county.value
        document.eosmail.cust_state.value   = parent.headframe.document.forms[0].state.value
        document.eosmail.cust_zip.value     = document.orders.zip.value
        document.eosmail.cust_country.value = document.orders.country.value
        document.eosmail.cust_phone.value   = document.orders.phone.value
        document.eosmail.cust_phone2.value  = document.orders.phone2.value
        document.eosmail.cust_fax.value     = document.orders.fax.value
        document.eosmail.cust_email.value   = document.orders.email.value
        document.eosmail.cust_email2.value  = document.orders.email2.value
        document.eosmail.cust_user1.value   = document.orders.user1.value
        document.eosmail.cust_user2.value   = document.orders.user2.value
        document.eosmail.cust_user3.value   = document.orders.user3.value
        document.eosmail.cust_text1.value   = document.orders.text1.value

        if(CC_accept == "eosmail") {
            document.eosmail.cust_ccc.value     = CC_cardList
            document.eosmail.cust_cc3dc.value   = CC_securityCode   // 0/1/2
            document.eosmail.cust_ccexp.value   = currency
            document.eosmail.cust_ccnum.value   = ""            // must be empty!
        } else {
            document.eosmail.cust_ccc.value     = parent.headframe.document.forms[0].ccc.value
            document.eosmail.cust_ccname.value  = document.orders.ccname.value
            document.eosmail.cust_ccnum.value   = document.orders.ccnum.value
            if(document.orders.ccexp.value != "mm/yyyy")
            document.eosmail.cust_ccexp.value   = document.orders.ccexp.value
            document.eosmail.cust_cc3dc.value   = document.orders.cc3dc.value
        }
        document.eosmail.cust_opt1.value    = parent.headframe.document.forms[0].cust_opt1.value
        document.eosmail.cust_opt2.value    = parent.headframe.document.forms[0].cust_opt2.value
        document.eosmail.cust_opt3.value    = parent.headframe.document.forms[0].cust_opt3.value
        document.eosmail.info1.value        = parent.headframe.document.forms[0].info1.value
        document.eosmail.info2.value        = parent.headframe.document.forms[0].info2.value
        document.eosmail.info3.value        = parent.headframe.document.forms[0].info3.value

        document.eosmail.checkout.value     = checkout          // eosmail, 2checkout, paypal, test, ...
        document.eosmail.returnLink.value   = returnLink
        document.eosmail.tagged.value       = TagFile
        document.eosmail.matrix.value       = replaceHTMLtags(MatrixFile.replace(/<br>/g," "))
        order_text_value = replaceHTMLtags(format_order(checkout))
        order_text_value = order_text_value.replace(/&quot;/g, "\"")
        order_text_value = escape(order_text_value)
        order_text_value = order_text_value.replace(/%u20AC/g, "EUR ")
        document.eosmail.order_text.value   = order_text_value
        document.eosmail.submit()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to make assumptions cause the question is blurry. It could be some extension installed in customer's browser like AdBlock.

The most optimal option here is to ask your customer to reproduce the issue in front of you or share HAR file. Pay attention on installed extensions and on requests in Network (DevTools).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @tetta I realize this is a hard ask. My customers are just people trying to order photos of their kids from an event and getting them to produce a HAR file is going to be impossible. Even getting them to tell me which model phone or computer and installed system results in the question "what are you talking about"

Comment: Please add code for functions `checkCustomerForm` and `submit_online`.
Other thoughts: javascript may be disabled for some customers, try https://www.browserstack.com/ for testing on different devices.

Comment: @tetta  I added the code you requested and really appreciate your looking at this. I spoke to another customer and they used an iPhone 14 pro this year and had problems, last year it was a different iPhone and no problems.

Answer (score 0):

After huge investigation I found what could be the reason of such "inactive" buttons.
I've tested the EOS template on a desktop browser. Everything works and there are no visible problems with the code.
During checkout it can show alert popup for some invalid fields `alert(errMsg)` or/and a confirmation dialog `confirm(myAlert)`.
But on the mobile device in chrome browser near the OK button there is a red button "Disable all pop-ups". Probably your customer just miss-clicked and choosed this red button.

Once I did the same the issue became reproducible and nothing happens on clicking checkout buttons.

**How to fix?** Open Chrome on customer device. Settings -> Content settings -> Block pop-ups -> Turn off.